# Change an App to use Browser instead of WebView

Tags: android, browser, webview, apktool

I have an Android app in my hands and I was decompiled it using Apktool.
Now, I have some .smali files and I want change that app to use Browser instead of WebView for opening a URL.
Which codes should I have to change?
Please Help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding the class where WebView's functionality is coded and remove any WebClient attached with it..compile and run it again.

Comment: Good to know this.. but I am not getting why some morons are down voting various question/answers without giving reasons..